# SOQL working in Excel but not Access

Tags: soql, api, query, excel

In Excel, I'm able to execute my query perfectly, with the help of Simba. The query is:

```
SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c Includes ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')
```

I am able to retrieve a table in Excel. When I try to run the same query in Access, I get an error:
[image]

Help? I can't figure out why it works one place, but not the other.

Comment: Have you tried using `IN()` instead?

Comment: That's getting closer - I don't get the error, but "Summit_History__c" is a multi-pick list. My new query is this:
`SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c in ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')`


I'm only returned rows of people with **only** that choice. Is there a way to adjust the query, so that I can get rows of any people who have this, but might also have something else?

Comment: try 
SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c in ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker','')
So the extra '' inlcludes null values
Source: http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/11/includes-keyword-in-soql.html